# Remove field in wsdl in Asp.net webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm generating dto classes with a template engine and would like to exclude some properties in an asmx webservice, what, if possible, is the best way to do this?

Ex:

```
[WebMethod]
public ProductPackages GetPackages()
{
   ProductPackages packages = new ProductPackages();
   packages.Packages.add(new PackageDTO());
   return packages;
}
```

The PackageDTO contains some properties that's not relevant for this service.
But as the class can be regenerated any time i can't apply [XmlIgnore] to the fields.

So I'm looking for a way to apply a "exclude list" without touching the actual class.
Above is just an example, the template engine generates dto's for all tables in a given project, and I would like to be able to use them in services without needing to maintain a big bunch of nearly identical classes.

Answer (score -1):

Just hit the same problem.  You can exclude fields by marking them as `internal`.

```
public class Order
{
    public double OrderPrice;
    internal double ProfitMargin;
    internal string TheTruthAboutThisCustomer;
}
```

Comment: -1: he says: "But as the class can be regenerated any time i can't apply [XmlIgnore] to the fields". I bet he can't change fields to `internal`, either.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to return a field or property, then don't have it in the object you return! It's as simple as that.

Comment: -1 he says: "But as the class can be regenerated any time i can't apply [XmlIgnore] to the fields". I bet he can't remove it from the object he returns, either

Comment: Duh - he should return a wrapper object, exposing only the fields he wants returned.